# glTexSubImage2D extremely slow on Intel video card

Tags: performance, opengl

My video card is Mobile Intel 4 Series. I'm updating a texture with changing data every frame, here's my main loop:

```
for(;;) {
    Timer timer;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE2D, tex);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); ... /* draw textured quad */ ... glEnd();
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE2D, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512,
        GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, data);
    swapBuffers();

    cout << timer.Elapsed();
}
```

Every iteration takes 120ms. However, inserting glFlush before glTexSubImage2D brings the iteration time to 2ms.

**The issue is not in the pixel format.** I've tried the pixel formats BGRA, RGBA and ABGR_EXT together with the pixel types UNSIGNED_BYTE, BYTE, UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 and UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_EXT. The texture's internal pixel format is RGBA.

**The order of calls matters.** Moving the texture upload before the quad drawing, for example, fixes the slowness.

I also tried this on an GeForce GT 420M card, and it works fast there. My real app does have performance problems on non-Intel cards that are fixed by glFlush calls, but I haven't distilled those to a test case yet.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Of course it works fast on a GT420. It's a GT420. But make it run faster on GMA, and even the nVidia will (should) be faster.

Comment: @genpfault: Windows 7 SP 1, driver version 8.15.10.2281

Comment: "Any ideas on how to debug this?" There is no bug here. Performance is not guaranteed anywhere. There's nothing to debug. It's just a quirk of Intel's graphics cards and OpenGL drivers; nothing more. You found a way that makes it faster, so you should use that.

Comment: @Nicol: Hey, let's not get hung up on the word bug :) If a slowdown happens for no visible reason, then I want to know what caused it so I can avoid it.

Comment: @StefanMonov: You assume that there is a reasonable cause, which you can then avoid in the future. There doesn't have to be, as shown by the fact that NVIDIA (and likely ATI) cards don't have this problem. And since you're dealing with Intel's notoriously buggy OpenGL drivers, it's even less likely that there's a logical cause for this. The best you can do in these situations is to recognize when you did something that caused an oddball performance hitch, try to rearrange your code to make it not happen, and note what you did for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

One issue is that `glTexImage2D` performs a full reinitialization of the texture object. If only the data changes, but the format remains the same, use `glTexSubImage2D` to speed things up (just a reminder).

The other issue is, that despite its name the immediate mode, i.e. glBegin(…) … glEnd() the drawing calls are not synchronous, i.e. the calls return long before the GPU is done drawing. Adding a glFinish() will synchronize. But as well will do calls to anything that modifies data still required by queued operations. So in your case glTexImage2D (and glTexSubImage2D) must wait for the drawing to finish.

Usually it's best to do all volatile resource uploads at either the beginning of the drawing function, or during the SwapBuffers block in a separate thread through buffer objects. Buffer objects have been introduced for that very reason, to allow for asynchronous, yet tight operation.

Comment: By the way, he does and has always used `glTexSubImage2D`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Thanks… Gah, I shouldn't answer on StackOverflow at work, too much distractions ;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize glTexSubImage2D will have to wait for the drawing to finish. Useful info. However this still can't cause a slowdown from 2ms to 120ms.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're actually using that texture for one or more of your quads?

Uploading textures is one of the most expensive operations possible.  Since your texture data changes every frame, the upload is unavoidable, but you should try to do it when the texture isn't in use by shaders.  Remember that `glBegin(GL_QUADS); ... glEnd();` doesn't actually draw quads, it requests that the GPU render the quads.  Until the rendering completes, the texture will be locked.  Depending on the implementation, this might cause the texture upload to wait (ala `glFlush`), but it could also cause the upload to fail, in which case you've wasted megabytes of PCIe bandwidth and the driver has to retry.

It sounds like you already have a solution: upload all new textures at the beginning of the frame.  So what's your question?

NOTE: Intel integrated graphics are horribly slow anyway.

Comment: Thanks, uploading textures in the beginning of the frame sounds sensible. As to "what's my question", well, I'd like to know what was happening in the videocard internals that was causing a slowdown from 2ms to 120ms. The "upload failure" thing you mentioned is new to me and sounds interesting, but I don't think it can account for such a slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a Draw Call ( glDrawElements, other ), the driver simply add this call in a buffer, and let the GPU consume these commands when it can.

If this buffer had to be consumed entirely at `glSwapBuffers`, this would mean that the GPU would be idle after that, waiting for you to send new commands.

Drivers solve this by letting the GPU lag one frame behind. This is the first reason why `glTexSubImage2D` blocks : the driver waits for the GPU not to use it anymore (in the previous frame) to begin the transfer, so that you never get half-updated data.

The other reason is that `glTexSubImage2D` is synchronous. Il will also block during the whole transfer.

- You can solve the first issue by keeping 2 textures : one for the current frame, one for the previous frame. Upload the texture in the former, but draw with the latter.
- You can solve the second issue by using a GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER Buffer Object, which allows asynchronous transfers.

In your case, I suspect that calling `glTexSubImage2D` just before glSwapBuffer adds an extra synchronization in the driver, whereas drawing the quad just before glSwapBuffer simply appends the command in the buffer. 120ms is probably a driver bug, though : even an Intel GMA doesn't need 120ms to upload a 512x512 texture.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably do the "2 textures" optimization as it sounds good, but I'm more interested in figuring out what was causing the huge slowdown mentioned in my question. Can't have been due to the synchronization alone. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, I think your technique won't actually speed things up. `glTexSubImage2D` won't return until the data has been transferred, right? So, when it does return, the data has already been transferred. Then drawing doesn't have to wait for anything. What am I missing?

Comment: `glTexSubImage2D` will block during the transfer, yes. But without double-buffering, it will also block while the GPU is using it to render stuff from the previous frame.

Comment: *"it will also block while the GPU is using it to render stuff from the previous frame."* - I don't get it. The previous frame is over, it has been flushed by swapBuffers. Can you break the explanation down for me?